# Migrate ASMX web service to servicestack

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, servicestack

We are moving from hosting in IIS to hosting our web service in self hosting nancy.

We have REST entry points working fine in self hosted nancy.

We also have a SOAP entry point that is surfaced as an ASMX. It appears to us that there is no practical way to run the asmx in self hosted nancy.

So we are looking at recreating the SOAP endpoint using servicestack.

Is there a doc or workflow to help us see the path forward?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack's [SOAP Support](http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support) docs contains info on hosting ServiceStack Services via SOAP (which requires ASP.NET).

Note it's only for making ServiceStack Services available via SOAP Endpoints, not for being able to host existing WCF/ASMX services.

Comment: I know we cannot host an asmx in service stack. Our idea is to recreate the current asmx SOAP endpoint using servicestack